# Alignment trap: not handling instruction e1913f9f at [<80467364>]

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm getting "alignment trap: not handling instruction" issue from kernel when I do i2c write using my own ioctl i2c write function in application.

Actually I written my own driver for a camera, have i2c read/write function to control the camera (control path).

This is my code which I used to access the i2c for write purpose.

This issue is coming after few runs of i2c write in application or first run itself....
So, we can't predict the issue occurring.

I have seen this case too, after single run, we would get this issue after few minutes.

I don't know know what could be the problem.
BTW, I have i2c read function in same manner but without having any "kmalloc" or memory alloc/free.
And its working without any problem.

In code, if I commented out the "kfree(temp_buff)", then I'm not getting this 'alignment' trap issue', but its not recommended right ?.

Can any one help me on this problem ?

```
    static s32 ioctl_i2cwrite(struct v4l2_int_device *s, struct v4l2_i2c *i2c_reg)
    {
        int j = 0, i = 0, ret = 0, reg_size_bkp = 0;
    //Titus
        int total_size = i2c_reg->count + i2c_reg->reg_size;    
        u8 i2c_w_buf [total_size];
        char *temp_buff;


    //  int total_size = 3;
    //  u8 i2c_w_buf[3];


        printk("Titus : i2c_write executed! %s : %d, total_size -> %d\n",__func__,__LINE__,total_size);


    //  temp_buff = kmalloc(i2c_reg->count * sizeof(char), GFP_KERNEL);
        temp_buff = kmalloc(i2c_reg->count, GFP_KERNEL);
        if(temp_buff == NULL){
            printk("failed to allocate memory:\n");
            return -1;  
        }

        memset(temp_buff, 0, i2c_reg->count);
        memcpy(temp_buff, i2c_reg->buffer, i2c_reg->count);
    /*
        ret = copy_from_user(temp_buff,i2c_reg->buffer,i2c_reg->count);
        if(ret != 0)
        {
        pr_err("copy_from_user is failed... %s %d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);
        kfree(temp_buff);
        return ret; 
        }
    */

        /* Backup the size of register which needs to be read after filling the address buffer */
        reg_size_bkp = i2c_reg->reg_size;
        printk(" i2c_write: reg_size_bkp=%d i2c_reg->reg_size=%d  %s\n",reg_size_bkp,i2c_reg->reg_size, __FILE__);


        // Fill the address in buffer upto size of address want to write */
        for(i = --i2c_reg->reg_size; i >= 0 ; i--,j++)              
            i2c_w_buf[i] = ((i2c_reg->reg >> (8*j)) & 0xFF);    

        /* Append the data value in the same buffer  */
        for(i = reg_size_bkp; i < (i2c_reg->count + reg_size_bkp) ; i++,temp_buff++)
            i2c_w_buf[i] = *temp_buff;

        ret = i2c_master_send(leonardo_data.i2c_client, i2c_w_buf, total_size );

        //TODO: Titus: It leads to alignment trap issue.
        kfree(temp_buff);


        return ret;
}
```

> root@imx6:/# root@imx6:/# Alignment trap: not handling instruction
>   e1913f9f at [<80467364>] Unhandled fault: alignment exception (0x001)
>   at 0x9e383d41 Internal error: : 1 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM Modules linked
>   in: ov5642_camera mxc_v4l2_capture ipu_bg_overlay_sdc ipu_still
>   ipu_prp_enc ipu_csi_enc adv7180_tvin ipu_fg_overlay_sdc
>   v4l2_int_device gpio_keys usb_f_ecm g_ether usb_f_rndis u_ether
>   libcomposite CPU: 1 PID: 935 Comm: Xorg Not tainted 3.14.52-svn99 #2
>   task: a8ace3c0 ti: a8d38000 task.ti: a8d38000 PC is at
>   gckOS_AtomIncrement+0x1c/0x48 LR is at
>   gckVIDMEM_NODE_Allocate+0x100/0x13c pc : [<80467368>]    lr :
>   [<8047b810>]    psr: a00f0013 sp : a8d39c50  ip : a8d39c60  fp :
>   a8d39c5c r10: 00000006  r9 : a8ec7e80  r8 : 00000009 r7 : a8846700  r6
>   : 00000000  r5 : a8846300  r4 : 9e383240 r3 : 00000000  r2 : a8d39c6c 
>   r1 : 9e383d41  r0 : a8846300 Flags: NzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode
>   SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user Control: 10c5387d  Table: 3840404a  DAC:
>   00000015 Process Xorg (pid: 935, stack limit = 0xa8d38238) Stack:
>   (0xa8d39c50 to 0xa8d3a000) 9c40:
>   a8d39c9c a8d39c60 8047b810 80467358 9c60: 800dd984 9e383240 00000000
>   a8ec7e80 a868c540 00000009 00000007 00000002 9c80: 00000006 00000001
>   a8846700 00004000 a8d39cfc a8d39ca0 8046ecfc 8047b71c 9ca0: a8d39ccc
>   a8d39cb0 800ddb1c 80052c24 a8819a00 000003a7 00004000 a8d39db8 9cc0:
>   000000cc a8b37cc0 a8ec7e80 00000000 a8b37eb4 ffffffff 00000000
>   a8d39d88 9ce0: a8846700 00000000 a8d38000 00000001 a8d39d5c a8d39d00
>   80471768 8046ea34 9d00: 00000040 00000006 00000003 a8d39dbc 00000000
>   00100100 00000000 00000000 9d20: 00000000 000003a7 a8b37eb4 00000000
>   ffffffff 00000000 a8844600 a8de7540 9d40: a8d38000 00007530 a8104338
>   7e8f38f8 a8d39ef4 a8d39d60 8046d848 80470d9c
>
> 9d60: 00000000 00000000 7e8f3970 00000000 00000140 00000000 7e8f3970
>   00000000 9d80: 00000140 00000000 00000007 00000002 00000000 00000000
>   00000000 00000000 9da0: 00000000 00000000 00004000 00000040 00000006
>   00000003 00000001 00000000 9dc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>   00000000 00000000 00000000 7e8f39d8 9de0: 00000000 76fa4000 76f6e6fd
>   76f9899c 00000017 76e4ff10 00001000 ffffffff 9e00: fffffff0 783b79f0
>   00001000 00000000 00000000 7e8f39ec 00000001 7e8f3a10 root@imx6:/#
>   9e20: 00000000 00000000 00000020 76f674a3 00000000 00000002 00000000
>   76fab554 9e40: 7835f998 76b89000 00000009 76fb018c 76fb018c 76fb018c
>   76fb018c 76fb018c 9e60: 78153960 00000000 78382c70 765746b3 00000000
>   00000000 00000000 00000000 9e80: 00000000 00000000 00000000 76b894e8
>   7e8f3ae4 00000044 7e8f3ad0 00000028 9ea0: 0000001a 783fac14 00000000
>   76afbe9d 00000000 00000000 00000040 7e8f3ae4 9ec0: 780d6228 766ce63c
>   a8d39ef4 a82f4780 a82f4780 00007530 7e8f38f8 a8104338 9ee0: a8d38000
>   7e8f38f8 a8d39f7c a8d39ef8 800f26fc 8046d728 8004e090 8004dcb8 9f00:
>   a8d39f1c a8d39f10 7e8f3a10 7e8f39f4 00000000 00000129 8000eae4
>   a63ed680 9f20: 7e8f39f4 00000000 00000129 8000eae4 a8d38000 00000000
>   a8d39f94 a8d39f48 9f40: 80507e24 805067b4 00000000 00000001 7e8f3c48
>   a82f4780 a82f4780 00007530 9f60: 7e8f38f8 00000009 a8d38000 00000000
>   a8d39fa4 a8d39f80 800f2c50 800f2688 9f80: 780d6228 00002710 766f2548
>   00007530 00000036 8000eae4 00000000 a8d39fa8 9fa0: 8000e960 800f2c20
>   00002710 766f2548 00000009 00007530 7e8f38f8 780d6228 9fc0: 00002710
>   766f2548 00007530 00000036 00000028 0000001a 783fac14 00000000 9fe0:
>   766e7550 7e8f38e4 766cf9d8 76b342b6 800f0030 00000009 3bf58811
>   3bf58c11 Backtrace: [<8046734c>] (gckOS_AtomIncrement) from
>   [<8047b810>] (gckVIDMEM_NODE_Allocate+0x100/0x13c) [<8047b710>]
>   (gckVIDMEM_NODE_Allocate) from [<8046ecfc>]
>   (gckKERNEL_AllocateLinearMemory+0x2d4/0x338)  r10:00004000 r9:a8846700
>   r8:00000001 r7:00000006 r6:00000002 r5:00000007  r4:00000009
>   [<8046ea28>] (gckKERNEL_AllocateLinearMemory) from [<80471768>]
>   (gckKERNEL_Dispatch+0x9d8/0x1080)  r10:00000001 r9:a8d38000
>   r8:00000000 r7:a8846700 r6:a8d39d88 r5:00000000  r4:ffffffff
>   [<80470d90>] (gckKERNEL_Dispatch) from [<8046d848>]
>   (drv_ioctl+0x12c/0x2b8)  r10:7e8f38f8 r8:a8104338 r7:00007530
>   r6:a8d38000 r5:a8de7540 r4:a8844600 [<8046d71c>] (drv_ioctl) from
>   [<800f26fc>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x80/0x598)  r10:7e8f38f8 r9:a8d38000
>   r8:a8104338 r7:7e8f38f8 r6:00007530 r5:a82f4780  r4:a82f4780
>   [<800f267c>] (do_vfs_ioctl) from [<800f2c50>] (SyS_ioctl+0x3c/0x60) 
>   r10:00000000 r9:a8d38000 r8:00000009 r7:7e8f38f8 r6:00007530
>   r5:a82f4780  r4:a82f4780 [<800f2c14>] (SyS_ioctl) from [<8000e960>]
>   (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x38)  r8:8000eae4 r7:00000036 r6:00007530
>   r5:766f2548 r4:00002710 r3:780d6228 Code: e3510000 0a00000a f57ff05b
>   e1913f9f (e2833001)
>   ---[ end trace 095d3b4029173c21 ]---
>   ------------[ cut here ]------------ Kernel BUG at 800dda80 [verbose debug info unavailable] Internal error: Oops - BUG: 0 [#2] PREEMPT SMP
>   ARM Modules linked in: ov5642_camera mxc_v4l2_capture
>   ipu_bg_overlay_sdc ipu_stillCPU: 2 PID: 754 Comm: NetworkManager
>   Tainted: G      D      3.14.52-svn99 #2 task: a8349300 ti: a8526000
>   task.ti: a8526000 PC is at kfree+0x18c/0x198 LR is at
>   inotify_free_event+0x10/0x14 pc : [<800dda80>]    lr : [<8011db68>]
>   psr: 40010013 sp : a8527e80  ip : 80934240  fp : a8527eb4 r10:
>   00000800  r9 : a8bea6c8  r8 : a8526000 r7 : abb1e000  r6 : 7e8e4124 
>   r5 : 9e380000  r4 : 00000020 r3 : 00000000  r2 : ab757000  r1 :
>   00000000  r0 : 00000000 Flags: nZcv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32 
>   ISA ARM  Segment user Control: 10c5387d  Table: 3866404a  DAC:
>   00000015 Process NetworkManager (pid: 754, stack limit = 0xa8526238)
>   Stack: (0xa8527e80 to 0xa8528000) 7e80: 800f34e0 0001352e 8005de80
>   00000020 00000005 7e8e4124 a8bea6c0 a8526000 7ea0: a8bea6c8 00000800
>   a8527ec4 a8527eb8 8011db68 800dd900 a8527ed4 a8527ec8 7ec0: 8011bec4
>   8011db64 a8527f44 a8527ed8 8011e168 8011bea0 a8527f44 7e8e4134 7ee0:
>   00000010 a8bea780 7e8e4124 a8bea6e8 a8527f44 00000001 00000080
>   00000282 7f00: 00000010 00000000 a8349300 8006657c a8527f10 a8527f10
>   a8d8f600 a8bea780 7f20: 00000800 7e8e4124 a8527f78 00000800 a8526000
>   7e8e4124 a8527f74 a8527f48 7f40: 800e2e64 8011df5c 800fc0a4 800fc024
>   00000000 00000000 a8bea781 a8bea780 7f60: 00000800 7e8e4124 a8527fa4
>   a8527f78 800e303c 800e2dd8 00000000 00000000 7f80: 7e8e411c 0000000a
>   7e8e4124 00000003 8000eae4 00000000 00000000 a8527fa8 7fa0: 8000e960
>   800e3004 7e8e411c 0000000a 0000000a 7e8e4124 00000800 00000000 7fc0:
>   7e8e411c 0000000a 7e8e4124 00000003 004cc0b0 76bdc5b8 004dcdd8
>   0005a195 7fe0: 00000000 7e8e4110 76a99619 76a99620 80010030 0000000a
>   3bf5e821 3bf5ec21 Backtrace: [<800dd8f4>] (kfree) from [<8011db68>]
>   (inotify_free_event+0x10/0x14)  r10:00000800 r9:a8bea6c8 r8:a8526000
>   r7:a8bea6c0 r6:7e8e4124 r5:00000005  r4:00000020 [<8011db58>]
>   (inotify_free_event) from [<8011bec4>]
>   (fsnotify_destroy_event+0x30/0x34) [<8011be94>]
>   (fsnotify_destroy_event) from [<8011e168>] (inotify_read+0x218/0x2f8)
>   [<8011df50>] (inotify_read) from [<800e2e64>] (vfs_read+0x98/0x138) 
>   r10:7e8e4124 r9:a8526000 r8:00000800 r7:a8527f78 r6:7e8e4124
>   r5:00000800  r4:a8bea780 [<800e2dcc>] (vfs_read) from [<800e303c>]
>   (SyS_read+0x44/0x90)  r10:7e8e4124 r8:00000800 r7:a8bea780 r6:a8bea781
>   r5:00000000 r4:00000000 [<800e2ff8>] (SyS_read) from [<8000e960>]
>   (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x38)  r10:00000000 r8:8000eae4 r7:00000003
>   r6:7e8e4124 r5:0000000a r4:7e8e411c Code: e7923283 e3130902 11a07001
>   eaffffb0 (e7f001f2)
>   ---[ end trace 095d3b4029173c22 ]--- power_down_callback: ipu0/csi0  ipu_prp_enc ipu_csi_enc adv7180_tvin ipu_fg_overlay_sdc
>   v4l2_int_device gpio_keys usb_f_ecm g_ether usb_f_rndis u_ether
>   libcomposite mxc_sdc_fb fb.20: 1280x720 h_sync,r,l: 40,110,220 
>   v_sync,l,u: 5,5,20 pixclock=74250000 Hz imx-ipuv3 2800000.ipu: try ipu
>   internal clk imx-ipuv3 2800000.ipu: disp=0, pixel_clk=74250000
>   74250000 parent=74250000 div=1 mxc_sdc_fb fb.20: 1280x720 h_sync,r,l:
>   40,110,220  v_sync,l,u: 5,5,20 pixclock=74250000 Hz imx-ipuv3
>   2800000.ipu: try ipu internal clk imx-ipuv3 2800000.ipu: disp=0, pixel_clk=74250000 74250000 parent=74250000 div=1 mxc_sdc_fb fb.20:
>   1280x720 h_sync,r,l: 40,110,220  v_sync,l,u: 5,5,20 pixclock=74250000
>   Hz imx-ipuv3 2800000.ipu: try ipu internal clk imx-ipuv3 2800000.ipu:
>   disp=0, pixel_clk=74250000 74250000 parent=74250000 div=1 mxc_sdc_fb
>   fb.20: 1280x720 h_sync,r,l: 40,110,220  v_sync,l,u: 5,5,20
>   pixclock=74250000 Hz imx-ipuv3 2800000.ipu: try ipu internal clk
>   imx-ipuv3 2800000.ipu: disp=0, pixel_clk=74250000 74250000
>   parent=74250000 div=1 Unable to handle kernel paging request at
>   virtual address 0024d8ac pgd = a9390000 [0024d8ac] *pgd=00000000

Regards,
Titus S.

Comment: What architecture? Alignment traps are an architecture-specific issue.

Comment: Its imx6 (ARM cortex A9) 32 bit arch.

Comment: The `--i2c_reg->reg_size` part of `for(i = --i2c_reg->reg_size; i >= 0 ; i--,j++)` seems suspect.  Why would you need to alter reg_size?  Do you really mean `i=(i2c_reg->reg_size-1);`?

Answer (score 3):

```
for(i = reg_size_bkp; i < (i2c_reg->count + reg_size_bkp) ; i++,temp_buff++)
```

In this line, you're incrementing the temp_buff pointer, so you're losing address of the start of the memory you malloc'd.  When you go to `free()`, you're freeing some random address that is character-aligned, not necessarily word-aligned, and I'm guessing that's what's raising your alignment error. You need to pass to `free()` the same address that `malloc()` returned.

Comment: Excellent!, thanks 'lyst' for your answer. I hope it would work, let me try and update you, thanks again lyst and Jonathon for your replies.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can fix the issue ? I should not change/increase buffer "i2c_reg->buffer" since its used by user space, that's why I have created one more buffer for moving to other place....how can I change this ?

Comment: Are you asking how you can change your code so that you're passing to free() the same address that malloc() returned?  Or have you encountered another alignment error once you made the free()/malloc() change?

Comment: Yes lyst. Thank you.

Comment: As of now, I took back up that address to u32 variable and apply free.  `u32 temp_buiffer_bkp;   temp_buffer_bkp = temp_buffer;   kfree(temp_buffer_bkp);` is it okay ? or any other method we can do ?

Comment: Yes, that solution is fine.  Other method - you could eliminate `temp_buff` entirely if you just perform the `memcpy()` from `i2c_reg->buffer[]` directly into `&i2c_w_buff[i2c_reg->reg_size]` (if you stop decrementing that value in the for-loop).